# Gremlin-Python: Property existence check

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I can't seem to figure out an idiomatic way to filter nodes that have or don't have a certain property (regardless of its value).

Property exists:

```
> g.V().hasNot('weight', None).toList()
*** gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 599: Could not locate method: DefaultGraphTraversal.hasNot([weight, null])
```

Property doesn't exist:

```
> g.V().has('weight', None).toList()
*** gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 599: null:has([weight, null])
```

`hasKey()` returns no results:

```
> g.V().hasKey('weight')
```

Using gremlin-server 3.3.4

Comment: Got the hasNot() idea from here: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/mapreduce-pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, turns out this works:

```
g.V().has('weight')
```

It was just hard to find in the docs: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#has-step